# React native changing state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im learning react native, by building a simple weather application

In my index.ios.js I have:

```
const iconNames = {
  Clear: 'md-sunny',
  Rain: 'md-rainy',
  Thunderstorm: 'md-thunderstorm',
  Clouds: 'md-cloudy',
  Snow: 'md-snow',
  Drizzle: 'md-umbrella'
}

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    //loads before component loaded
    this.state = {
      temp: 0,
      weather: 'Clear'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    //loads after Component loads for first time
    this.getLocation()
  }

  getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (posData) => fetchWeather(posData.coords.latitude,posData.coords.longitude)
        .then(res => this.setState({
          temp:res.temp,
          weather:res.weather
        })),
      (error) => alert(error),
      {timeout:10000}
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar hidden={true}/>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Icon name={iconNames[this.state.weather]} size={80} color={'white'}/>
          <Text style={styles.temp}>{this.state.temp}°</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <Text>its raining</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle}>rain</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Im updating the weather icon state here:

```
<Icon name={iconNames[this.state.weather]} size={80} color={'white'}/>
```

Which changes the icon as expected, but the icon seems to disappear after a second, and when I reload the app the same happens. The icon appears then disappears.

If I hard code the value like this, the icon stays there as expected:

```
<Icon name={'md-snow'} size={80} color={'white'}/>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `res.weather` is not one of `iconNames` object's properties?

Comment: @PatrikPrevuznak i put some logs in the console and its comes back as the correct name... it does appear for a few seconds then disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Icon appears at the first time because you are setting a default value in your componentWillMount.

Then, after the component renders you call componentDidMount and tries to update the state on your getLocation method.

Assuming the Icon disappears after it renders, we can say the problem is in your getLocation method.

By checking the docs, it looks like you have to setup some permissions to use geolocation. Just make sure you have this allowed:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Then you call a `fetchWeather` method. I couldn't understand where did it came from. Check if it's working as expected.

And finally the piece where the error should be: `this.setState`. Try adding a console.log to your `res.weather` to check it's return. If it returns null, try adding `console.log(res)` to check what you are getting.

From this you may have the following scenarios:

1) Your res.weather or res is returning null. Then I suggest to check the docs of this method you are trying to use, maybe you forgot something. Also add some console.logs to make sure if your code is returning everything as expected.

2) Your res.weather returns a value which doesn't exists an icon with the same name. In this case you should use a `switch(res.weather) case` and set the state with the correctly string based on the return of your weather

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. i put some logs in and the data seems to be returning as expected with a value which is within the weather object

Comment: can you try removing your timeout?